# Operations on a big data frame

Tags: r

I have a big data frame that looks like this:

```
   P1_prom  Nom
1  -6.17  Pt_00187
2  -6.17  Pt_00187
3  -6.17  Pt_00187
4  -6.17  Pt_00187
5  -6.17  Pt_00187
6  -6.17  Pt_01418
7  -5.77  Pt_01418
8  -5.37  Pt_01418
9  -4.97  Pt_01418
10  -4.57  Pt_01418

-
-
-
25000
```

where Nom represents a point in a map, and P1_prom represents the value of an operation we perfomed on each point (note that we performed 5 repetitions for each point, hence, each point has 5 values).
What I am trying to do, with no success, is to create a new column, in which each row corresponds to the mean value of P1_prom for each point. So basically what I need the program to do is to write in the first row of the new column the average of the first five values of P1_prom, in the second row the average of the next five values, and so on.
Could anybody guide me on how to do this.
Thank you very much,
Veronica

Comment: look at the help pages for `tapply` (and all other `apply` functions), `by` and `aggregate`. if `dat` is your data `tapply(dat$P1_prom, dat$Nom, mean)` should work

Comment: The question is terribly unclear.  You talk of wanting to add a column, which would suggest the `ave` function.  But your description is of aggregating such that the new column would not be nearly the same length as the current data.frame.

Answer (score 5):

This is a job for `data.table`

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, name_of_new_column := mean(P1_prom), by=Nom]
```